# Cakephp update single field in database table

Tags: cakephp

Using cakephp 1.3 is there a simple example of how to update (not insert) a row in a database table?

```
  $data = array('list_index' => $id, 'name' => $name);
  if ($this->save($data)) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
```

Official documentation states that this is the way it should be done, however, it throws an errors as it attempts to do an insert with an existing primary key. Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$this->Post->read(null, 1);
$this->Post->set(array(
    'title' => 'New title',
    'published' => false
));
$this->Post->save();
```

Or

```
$this->Recipe->id = 2;
$this->Recipe->save($this->data);
```

From 1.3 Manual:

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html

Comment: Or you can use `Model::saveField`

Comment: Tried saveField, but cakephp says it is an undefined method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your model has the [`primaryKey`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#Model-Attributes#primaryKey-1061) value set corectly.

In this case, it should be

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {
  public $primaryKey = 'list_index';
  // ...
}
```

If you do no do that, CakePHP will try to insert instead of update.

Comment: Once you have properly set the primary key, save the field:

$this->ModeName->saveField('name', $name);